# Error passing java byte array as ColdFusion query parameter: mismatched input 'struct' expecting RIGHTPAREN

Tags: java, coldfusion, arrays

I am trying to convert some CF (version 10) code that was embedded inside a .cfm file into a function of a component as part of a Framework 1 application. The component is in script syntax, and the original code is in tag syntax. I didn't write the original code, and since I am still learning ColdFusion I am only trying to replicate the original code rather than re-write it.

The function reads in a file from the client and chops it up into pieces and stores the pieces in Java ByteArrays. It then makes as many queries as needed to store the byte arrays in a database. I have successfully converted everything up until the actual insertion query.

The problem I'm having is converting this portion of code, mainly the line with #objBuffer.Array()#:

```
<cfquery name="insertFile" datasource="#Datasource#">
    INSERT INTO wt_file (file_data,file_name,file_type,file_part,rec_id)
    VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam value="#objBuffer.Array()#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_blob">, 
        <cfqueryparam value="#rc.fileName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#rc.fileType#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">, 
        <cfqueryparam value="#i#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">, 
        <cfqueryparam value="#rc.rec_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)
</cfquery>
```

objBuffer.Array() is calling the Java method Array() on a java ByteBuffer object. When i try to do the same in script syntax like this:

```
fileQuery = new Query(
    name="insertFile",
    datasource = Datasource,
    sql = "INSERT INTO wt_file
                (file_data, file_name, file_type, file_part, rec_id)
                VALUES (:data, :name, :type, :part, :recid)");

fileQuery.addParam(name="data", value = objBuffer.Array(), cfsqltype="CF_SQL_blob");
fileQuery.addParam(name="name", value = rc.fileName, cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
fileQuery.addParam(name="type", value=rc.fileType, cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
fileQuery.addParam(name="part", value=i, cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
fileQuery.addParam(name="recid", value=rc.rec_id, cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");

/*execute query*/
fileQuery.execute();
```

In this syntax, the objBuffer.Array() call breaks the entire function. I have tried calling it before the parameter and passing it via a variable, but it doesn't matter where I call it. I get the same results.

The error message eclipse is giving me is  not very helpful, but I'll post it anyway:

```
mismatched input 'struct' expecting RIGHTPAREN       
0cfml.parsing.cfscript.CFParseException
null struct 137org.antlr.runtime.NoViableAltException
null function 52org.antlr.runtime.NoViableAltException
missing SEMICOLON at '('  0cfml.parsing.cfscript.CFParseException
null function 52org.antlr.runtime.NoViableAltException
```

Because I am merely converting code, I am sure the is a better way to do this. I am sure there is a way to do this without using java classes but if there is a way to make this work too it would be great. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of CF? Worked fine with CF11.  *I have tried ... passing it via a variable* Are you 100% certain? Going strictly by the error message it does sound like a problem with parenthesis, and switching to a variable should fix that (assuming the correct placement), ie `, value = theBinaryVariable, ...`

Comment: I am using CF10. I have indeed tried to save it into a variable like this: var z = objBuffer.Array(); and then passing z as the value just as you did in your comment but I still get the error. The error goes away as soon as I comment the Array() call out though.

Comment: Wonder if it might be a bug with CF10.  Unfortunately I cannot test with CF10 right now. I assume you dumped the `z` variable and verified it contains the expected binary array, not something else, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot even get the component this function is in to run because it breaks the entire function. The file is called addFile.cfc and i get this error when framework One tries to run it as a Service: 
    Element ADDFILESERVICE is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;.

Comment: Just to rule out possible issues with other code in the component, try a scaled down example in a *totally* separate script. Just the variables and query code: http://trycf.com/gist/0baf66b668b19006ab189db2f0a628a2/acf2016?theme=monokai . Try it both ways, ie with `objBuffer.Array()` and using a variable instead.

Comment: @zephos2014 Are you sure `objBuffer.Array()` is returning binary?

Comment: No I'm not completely sure. The weird thing is the code works in tag syntax, so i can't imagine it being that.

Comment: What happened when you tried the [simple test case](http://trycf.com/gist/0baf66b668b19006ab189db2f0a628a2/acf2016?theme=monokai)?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't run my code there. I can't take the risk of connecting to my actual datasource through a third party website.

Comment: @zephos2014 - No, you misunderstood me :). You *cannot* run db queries on that site - even if you wanted to. The gist is simply a quick way to share code snippets, so we are both testing the exact same thing. Run that code in *your* environment and check the results. I suspect you will still get the same error, but that would at least rule out problems elsewhere in the component (since the same code works with CF11).

Comment: @Leigh oh okay. I'm totally new to this kind of development so I'm out of my comfort zone here. I see what you mean now. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: @Leigh I get the same error with your code in my environment.

Comment: @zephos2014 - No worries at all. Normally trycf.com snippets *are* "runnable" (as that is the whole point of the site :-)  But certain things like db queries or things that require file access are restricted. Since I was already on trycf.com, it was simpler to use its gist feature. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: (Edit) Just to be sure we are on the same page, aside from updating the DSN name, you ran the example *exactly* as is - on a totally separate page? Did the error occur when using a variable too? Because if parentheses are the problem, it seems strange that substituting a variable does not fix that. Here's what I used with CF11: http://trycf.com/gist/ff89b2f0d660a9e5665fd5b2e4be9af7/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: The function breaks - eclipse throws an error. I can try to run it but I guarantee it won't work as it is the exact same behavior as my own code and it fails to run. FW/1 doesn't recognize the service because the component is broken, so when i try to call it it fails miserably.

Comment: It fails to run because it can't find the service, probably because it is broken.

Comment: *The function breaks* @zephos2014 - I do not think we are talking about the same thing. I am talking about running a simplified - **and totally separate** - test case. One that contains only the query code (no extra functions, components or FW/1). Copy and paste the example from the link into a separate .cfm script, change the DSN name and run it. That is it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118656/discussion-between-leigh-and-zephos2014).